# Don't redirect somewhere instead of returning 404

Tags: nextcloud, http-status-code-404

When I visit a URL handled by my Nextcloud instance that does not exit -- like https://example.com/nextcloud/doesnotexist or https://example.com/index.php/nextcloud/doesnotexist -- it redirects to /nextcloud/apps/files instead of returning a 404 error. How to fix this?